# Get number value from name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is a better way of getting the numbers from `name="staff_member[]"`?

In my example below, I seem to get the error which is displayed below sometimes.

```js
$(".remove_button").each(function(index, value){
  document.write($(this).parent().next("input").attr("name").replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div>
  <div class="remove_button"></div>
 </div>
 <input name="staff_member[15]" />
 <div>
  <div class="remove_button"></div>
 </div>
 <input name="staff_member[16]" />
 <div>
  <div class="remove_button"></div>
 </div>
 <input name="staff_member[21]" />
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
>       at deselect_staff_member (direct.message.js:55)
>       at HTMLSpanElement. (direct.message.js:153)
>       at HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
>       at HTMLSpanElement.i (jquery.js:3)

Comment: do divs have names? why not change to ids?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs - My bad, this is better. I've changed the divs to inputs. I'm using the staff_member as posts values. So i'm just using this as a way of showing the user they've selected the current value